# JSON Reader issue: cannot access jsonData

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a strange thing going on here: I am using a JSON reader within a store to fetch search results. After loading the store I receive data or error states (built together as a JSON, too). So in both ways I get a successfully response, so I have to check the JSON for myself to trap "error conditions". But I cannot access the jsonData property that shhould be a JSON object within the reader. Chrome tells me that:

[image: Chrome Developer Tools]

I can access the applyDefaults though (it returns true in that case) but not the jsonData.
My code looks like this:

```
var result = searchStore.getProxy().getReader();
console.log(result.jsonData);
```

The output is "undefined". As you can see in the picture the jsonData object holds my JSON (with the isError property I wanted to access).

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Probably a timing issue. By the time you're inspecting it in the console, the request has completed. When you're logging it, it hasn't.

Comment: It seems so... I am testing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think more async and think of the timing it takes for a request to return and when you are trying to get the jsonData. Instead of using console.log, set a breakpoint or use the `debugger;` statement so you can freeze the browser and walk through the code. You can then inspect variables and such to see what the object looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access your JSON data in a success callback, to make sure the data is gathered from the server.